# How does spring boot return byte stream in real time like PHP's readfile function?

Tags: java, php, spring-boot, file

I am solving a requirement. I am using the springboot framework. Now there is an interface that passes in the parameter url. This url is a network file address. After receiving the request, the interface uses its own network to request the network file and returns it to the client in real time. , php's readfile function can solve the problem, but is there such a solution in the java language? What I need is to return to the client in real time, instead of reading all and returning to the client

```
@Controller
@Api(tags = "test")
@RequestMapping("/test")
@CrossOrigin
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value = "get")
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> test() throws IOException {
      
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"123\": 1}");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://github.com/xujimu/ios_super_sign/archive/refs/heads/master.zip")
                .method("GET", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by java's URL class

```
package com.api.controller;

import cn.dev33.satoken.annotation.SaCheckLogin;
import cn.dev33.satoken.stp.StpUtil;
import com.api.common.result.PageReq;
import com.api.common.result.PageResult;
import com.api.common.result.Result;
import com.api.common.user.AddBalanceReq;
import com.api.constant.ResultCode;
import com.api.dao.ApiUserDao;
import com.api.dao.UserFlowDao;
import com.api.entity.ApiUserEntity;
import com.api.entity.UserFlowEntity;
import com.api.execption.ResRunException;
import com.api.service.ApiUserService;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.pagination.Page;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Date;


@Controller
@Api(tags = "test")
@RequestMapping("/test")
@CrossOrigin
public class TestController {
 
    /**
     * 添加用户月
     *
     * @param req
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ApiOperation(value = "get")
    public void test(String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        URL url1 = new URL(url);

        InputStream is = url1.openStream();

        int ch;
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            response.getWriter().write(ch);
        }
        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>` for this.

You have choose which content-type you want to return. We ended up with `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE`.

We had to modify the way we did rest request by changing from `RestClient to` WebClient`:

```
Flux<DataBuffer> dataStream = return webClient.method(method)
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

DataBufferUtils.write(dataStream, response.getOutputStream())
                .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
                .blockLast();
```

When we finally got this to work, it works really well :)

You can see some other examples on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-sse-streams.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand your code, can you write a complete interface code example?

Comment: I think the best way for you to solve this is to write a testcase where you first do the restcall as you do now in your code and then change to use WebClient as in the example in my post. Then you can play with the code until you get it working.